# React native right justified wrapped text

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have a view where I want all of the text aligned to the right of the screen, even when wrapped.   I currently have:

```
<Block flex={1} style={{alignItems: "flex-end", alignContent: "flex-end", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
    <Text>{this.address.label}</Text>
...
```

The text is wrapping but still being aligned to the left.  Is there a way to change this behavior?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try textAlign: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalign

```
<Text style={{textAlign:'right'}}>{this.address.label}</Text>
```

Comment: Aha!  I don't know why I didn't try that... Adding that to the Text element fix it.  Thanks so much!